# Why should I leave JSON Web Token payload nonencrypted?

Tags: json, jwt

I'm reading on JWT, there are so many tutorials and so many approaches, it's confusing.

I have couple of questions regarding proper usage of JWTs:

1) I keep seeing inconsistent means of transporting JWTs to and from the server. [For example, here](https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/): one transport method for retrieving the token (via JSON-encoded object in POST body), another method for submitting it (via HTTP header). Why such inconsistency? Of course, it's up to the implementer to choose the methods, but wouldn't it be good practice at least to be consistent and use either only header or only body?

2) The JWT payload contains the information of state because the server is not maintaining it. It is obvious one should keep the size of the payload as small as possible, because the size of JWT is added to every request and response. Perhaps just a user id and cached permissions. When the client needs any information, it can receive it via (typically JSON-encoded) HTTP body and store it in the local storage, there seems to be no need to access the read-only JWT payload for the same purpose. So, why should one keep the JWT payload nonencrypted? Why mix the two ways of getting application data to the client and use both JWT payload and normal data-in-response-body? Shouldn't the best practice be to keep JWT always encrypted? It can be updated only on the server side anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I keep seeing inconsistent means of transporting JWTs to and from the server. [...] wouldn't it be good practice at least to be consistent and use either only header or only body?

This may depend on the Client. While a web app can get a higher degree of security by storing the JWT in cookie storage, native apps may prefere local storage in order to access the JWT information. [1]

> 2. The JWT payload contains the information of state because the server is not maintaining it. It is obvious one should keep the size of the payload as small as possible, because the size of JWT is added to every request and response. Perhaps just a user id and cached permissions. When the client needs any information, it can receive it via (typically JSON-encoded) HTTP body and store it in the local storage, there seems to be no need to access the read-only JWT payload for the same purpose.

The JWT keeps the Backend state, not the client state. The Backend state may be that `User 128 is logged in as administrator`. This is (in my example) stored in the JWT in the fields `Subject` and `Scopes`. Instead of the client sending an ID of a Backend session that contains this information, the info is in the JWT directly. The backend does thus not have to keep a session that stores the `logged in state` of user 128. If the Client requests information of `User 2`, the BE may decide that this info is forbidden if the JWT tells that the logged in user has ID 1.

> So, why should one keep the JWT payload nonencrypted?

The state is normally not secret to the client. The important factor is that the JWT is protected for manipulation (signed). The clien can even make use on the information in the JWT, like adjusting the GUI etc depending on the state. (Like showing a button for the admin GUI or not.) It can validate the JWT if a public key is used for validation, but there is often no point in doing that sub's the client code cannot be trusted.

> Why mix the two ways of getting application data to the client and use both JWT payload and normal data-in-response-body?

See above, the main purpose of the JWT is to keep information the the Backend, not the Client. Once the user loggs in, the Backend ask "Hey, can you hold this info for me and attach it to every request so that I can forget about you in the meantime?" Like if your manager asks you to wear a name sticker on your skirt so that he/she don't have to remember your name. :-) (And he/she signs it so that you cannot alter it without him/her noticing.

> Shouldn't the best practice be to keep JWT always encrypted? It can be updated only on the server side anyway.

It doesn't really bring any security unless you store secret information in the JWT, and that bay be better to do server side. The decryption is a bit more cumbersome to decrypt compared to just verifying a signature.

[1] [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)